# Obtaining gateway IP from Bash script fails, but works in terminal

Tags: bash, debian

I'm attempting to write a script in bash that will automatically add a line/replace a line in /etc/rsyslog.conf when the network Gateway changes.  This would enable distribution of an rsyslog server with directed logging to specific log file.

I haven't been able to determine why this fails and hoping someone with a better understanding can address.

The following is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
GETGATEWAY="route -n | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print \$2}'"
echo "This is a test"
echo $GETGATEWAY
shopt -s extglob
$GETGATEWAY
```

Result follows.

> This is a test route -n | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print $2}' Usage:
>   route [-nNvee] [-FC] []           List kernel routing tables
>          route [-v] [-FC] {add|del|flush} ...  Modify routing table for AF.
>
> ```
>    route {-h|--help} [<AF>]              Detailed usage syntax for specified AF.
>    route {-V|--version}                  Display version/author and exit.
>
>     -v, --verbose            be verbose
>     -n, --numeric            don't resolve names
>     -e, --extend             display other/more information
>     -F, --fib                display Forwarding Information Base (default)
>     -C, --cache              display routing cache instead of FIB
> ```
>
> =Use '-A ' or '--'; default: inet   List of possible
>   address families (which support routing):
>       inet (DARPA Internet) inet6 (IPv6) ax25 (AMPR AX.25) 
>       netrom (AMPR NET/ROM) ipx (Novell IPX) ddp (Appletalk DDP) 
>       x25 (CCITT X.25)

If you copy the echo line after "This is a test" and paste on the terminal to execute, it works as expected.
route -n | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print $2}'

I've tried multiple shell options with and without shopt -s extglob.

Comment: Needless use of an extra _pipe_ and `grep` when `route -n | awk '/UG[ \t]/{print $2}'` produces the same results as `route -n | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print $2}'` does!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are storing the command sequence in a variable and then trying to execute it through an evaluation (`$var`).  You could do this:

```
eval "$GETGATEWAY"
```

Without `eval`, shell interprets `route` as the command and everything else, including `|` etc., as arguments to it.  And `extglob` option has nothing to do with this.

You may want to take a look at this post:

[Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)

Answer (score 0):

you should use command substitution for computing the IP address and storing it to any variable.

```
var=$(command1|command2|....)
```

Example:

```
GATEWAY=$(route -n |awk '/UG/{print $2}')
echo $GATEWAY
10.1.1.1
```